# 5e Shapeshifting Druid rules

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, damage, wild-shape

I'm a bit confused with some of the rules stated in the Player's Handbook about Wild Shape.   Specifically, my question is about taking damage while in animal form: if my health drops to one HP, I revert back to humanoid form and take the remaining damage.

Does all the damage I would have taken in animal form transfer over to my actual humanoid health?

Comment: reversion occurs when you drop to 0, not 1.

Comment: Are you asking about forced reversion due to damage, or taking damage and then voluntarily reverting to humanoid shape?

Answer (score 9):

Your assumption is not correct, only the damage left over from the attack is transferred to your humanoid health.  (Think of Wild Shape as a type of "overshield" or "bonus health")

Ex:

> You have 12 HP in your beast form.  The barbarian that you are fighting hits you dealing 15 points of damage.  This leaves 3 HP left over.  So that remaining 3HP is dealt to your character's health pool.

Here is an example from the RAW

> When you transform, you assume the beasts hit points and Hit Dice.  When you revert to your normal form, you return to the number of hit points you had before you transformed.  However, if you revert as a result of dropping to 0 hit points, any excess damage carries over to your normal form.  For example, if you take 10 damage in animal form and only have 1 hit point left, you revert [to normal shape] and take 9 damage.  As long as the excess damage doesn't reduce your normal form to 0 hit points, you aren't knocked unconscious.

Comment: Your answer (description) is right, but the answer to their question (does *all* damage transfer over) is no -- only the excess after taking the beast down to zero hp carries over to the human form.  At least that's how I read the question, especially the subject header.

Comment: My apologies, when I wrote this answer it was pre-edit, the edit seems to have added the "all damage" or perhaps I am a terrible reader.  I will fix the answer to include.

Comment: I thought it might be the case that the edit confused the situation.

Answer (score 3):

## No unless you drop to 0 HP in Beast Form

Page 67 of the PHB states

> "When you revert to your normal form, you return to the number of hit
>   points you had **before** you had transformed".

Example: Let's say your normal form has 15 HP and then you transform into a 10 HP beast form.  Later you take 9 damage which drops you to 1 HP(while in beast form) and then you revert back to normal. In that case your HP will be 15 HP not 1 HP cause you assume the HP of your normal form before you had transformed.

#### The Exception: 0 HP

The exception to this rule being when you drop to 0 HP, in which case all excess damage is applied to your normal form.
  Example: If your beast form had 10 HP and you take 12 HP, you will return to your normal form and take 2 excess damage.